# Unable to Determine Proper Print Scale of STL model

Tags: 3d-models, slicing

I am new to 3D printing and have a *Monoprice MP Select Mini 3D Printer V2*. I wanted to be able to 3D-print [this VR Adapter](https://www.thingiverse.com/thing:4203631) from Thingiverse. Before downloading the Cura software, I tried opening the model in Print 3D, and as you can see in this picture, it appears that the model is just under 100 mm, which is well under the 120 mm limit of the MP Select Mini’s 120 mm×120 mm build plate:

[image: Print3D Scale]

However, when I downloaded Cura and input the specs for the printer (120 mm for *x, y,* and *z* dimensions), the model appears to be much larger than the 120×120×120 area. The program tells me that the model is 132.5 mm × 180.6 mm × 36.6 mm:

[image: Cura Scale]

I need the model to fit the controller for the Oculus Quest, so I can’t just scale it down. Can anyone tell me why I am seeing this discrepancy and how I can still print this model?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The STL format does not define unit information. So there is no way of knowing, from a STL file alone, what size it should be.

However there are only a handful of units people design with. So the unit is most likely one of inches, cm or mm. So if you inverse convert between those combinations you'll likely find the real size.

Your image is somewhat inconclusive. But it seems to indicate your object is in fact larger than your bed. As it it is 18-19 pips of height and i would interpret each as 10 mm from the image. Which would indicate your model is correct.

Split and glue? Print corner to corner you should have 207 mm length that way (but not necessarily width).